# can't find referenced class kotlin.KotlinPackage

Tags: android, kotlin, base64, proguard

I've tried adding "-dontwarn kotlin.KotlinPackage" to proguard-rules.pro but not working.
I'm using Base64 in my code and i can't find where is wrong. When i disable minify, there is no problem.

Warning

```
Warning: Base64Kt: can't find referenced class kotlin.KotlinPackage
```

My code

```
val decoded_note = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Base64.getDecoder().decode(LocalData.with(this@MainActivity.applicationContext).read(getString(R.string.hashed_note)).toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
    } else {
        android.util.Base64.decode(LocalData.with(this@MainActivity.applicationContext).read(getString(R.string.hashed_note)).toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT)
    }
    val old_note = String(decoded_note, charset("UTF-8"))
    note_EditText.setText(old_note)

    note_save_button.setOnClickListener{
        val new_note=note_EditText.text.toString()

        val hashed_note= if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(new_note.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8")))
        } else {
            android.util.Base64.encodeToString(new_note.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8")), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT)
        }

        LocalData.with(this@MainActivity.applicationContext).write(getString(R.string.hashed_note),hashed_note.toString())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem with cleaning up the project.
Build-->Clean Build